# Проблемы с модулем vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

При попытке запуска бота ВК выдаёт проблему:

```
  File "vk.py", line 1, in <module>
    import vk_api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vk_api'
```

А при попытке установки выдаёт:

```
pip install vk_api
Requirement already satisfied: vk_api in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from vk_api)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3.4" in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from vk_api)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from vk_api)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from requests->vk_api)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from requests->vk_api)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from requests->vk_api)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from requests->vk_api)
```

И я не знаю, что делать.

Comment: попробуй pip3 install vk_api

Comment: Какую версию `Python` Вы используете? Или, скорее, какую пытаетесь использовать? Ошибка связана с тем, что `pip` относится к интерпретатору `Python2.7`, а код Вы пытаетесь запустить, используя другой интерпретатор.

Answer (score 0):

Примеры в данной инструкции были сделаны в windows 10 и python 3.6.4 x64

Для корректной установки библиотек вам необходимо иметь правильно настроенное окружение, поэтому перед установкой проверьте условия, описанные ниже:
имя пользователя должно быть написано на латинице (это одно из ограничений windows);
в переменной окружения path должен быть путь до папки с python и до папки Scripts (которая располагается в папке с python);
python должен быть установлен "для всех пользователей", то есть установлен в "Program Files", либо в другую папку находящуюся в корне диска С.
Идеальным вариантом будет создать в корне диска C папку bin и устанавливать туда всё необходимое для разработки. Такой подход спасет от разных
неприятных недоразумений, связанных с ограничениями некоторых инструментов.

Пример:

> pip3 install (название библиотеки)